# Use dataset on task done on a certain timestamp to reconstruct a work schedule in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a very extensive dataset with loads of employees in R that have done a certain task at a certain time. An example is given below

[image]

```
emp <- c('a','b','c','c','d','d','e','e')
timestamp <- c('1-1-2020 10:00','1-1-2020 16:00','1-2-2020 06:30','1-2-2020 09:00','1-2-2020 20:00','1-3-2020 04:00','1-3-2020 05:00','1-3-2020 10:00')
```

From this information I want to extract in which shift on which day the employees were at work. From the current example I should get the following:

[image]

Moreover, I would like a column next to the shift definition that states how many seconds have passed between the start of the first shift (1-1-2020 22:00 - 06:00) and the current shift. This should look like this:

[image]

Anyone any idea how I can create such a work schedule in R? Preferably a solution using dplyr

Comment: Two comments: 1) first SHIFT is supposed to start 12-31-2019 22:00 it is ok? 2) between 22:00 and 14:00 there are 57600 seconds, not 48000. Doesn't it?

Comment: First point you are right. Second point you are not right: it is the time between the start and the start of the next shift - not the end of the next shift

Comment: So if each shift is 8 hr , time in seconds is 8 * 60 * 60 = 28800.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)

timestamp <- mdy_hm(timestamp)

starts <- seq(as_date(min(timestamp)) - hours(2), to = max(timestamp), by = "8 hours")

shifts <- lapply(starts, \(start) interval(start, start + hours(8)))

worked_in_shift <- \(shift, timestamp) any(timestamp %within% shift)

data.frame(
  shift = I(shifts),
  outer(
    shifts,
    split(timestamp, emp),
    Vectorize(worked_in_shift)
  )
)
```

```
         shift     a     b     c     d     e
1 2019-12-.... FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
2 2020-01-....  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3 2020-01-.... FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
4 2020-01-.... FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
5 2020-01-.... FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
6 2020-01-.... FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
7 2020-01-.... FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
8 2020-01-.... FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: This works for the test case I build but when I try and apply it on the real data I get "Error: unexpected input in "shifts <- lapply(starts, \"

Comment: Maybe you're using a version of R prior to 4.1 and the introduction of the `\ ` function shorthand notation. (Though if that's the case it shouldn't work either with the test case). Please try again replacing `\(start)` by `function(start)`, and `\(shift, timestamp)` by `function(shift, timestamp)`

Comment: That was the problem! The real data is in an environment which is indeed using an older version of R. Thanks for the help!

Comment: is there a way to get the start and end of the interval classes in seperate columns at the beginning of the df. And also to name them night, morning and day shifts in a seperate column? I have been trying with int_start(), map() and separate() but without success

Comment: Yes and yes. I realize now that `shifts` can be simplified further: `shifts <- interval(starts, starts + hours(8))`, which lets you use `int_start` without the need for `map`. "At the beginning of the df": `dplyr::relocate`. For night/morning/day nomenclature have a look at `dplyr::case_when`, or just use `rep()`. Unrelated: careful with daylight saving time, check if this naive approach matches the real world implications of DST for shifts.

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer based on data.table.
Data table has a "rolling join" feature which is very straigthfoward on this situations.

```r
library(data.table)

# data
df <- data.frame(
  emp = c('a','b','c','c','d','d','e','e'),
  timestamp = c('1-1-2020 10:00','1-1-2020 16:00','1-2-2020 06:30','1-2-2020 09:00',
              '1-2-2020 20:00','1-3-2020 04:00','1-3-2020 05:00','1-3-2020 10:00'))

# setting data.table 
# casting timestamp as time variable
setDT(df)
df$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(strptime( df$timestamp, "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M"))

# create table of "shifts"
periods <- data.table(
  SHIFT_from = seq.POSIXt( from = as.POSIXct("2019-12-31 22:00"), 
                           to = as.POSIXct("2020-01-03 14:00"), by = "8 hours"),
  SHIFT_to = seq.POSIXt( from = as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 06:00"), 
                         to = as.POSIXct("2020-01-03 22:00"), by = "8 hours")) 

# join (rolling) and calculate seconds. 
df <- df[periods, .(
    emp, 
    from = SHIFT_from, 
    to = SHIFT_to, 
    timestamp = x.timestamp, 
    secs = as.integer(difftime(i.SHIFT_from, i.SHIFT_from[1], units = "s"))), 
  on = c("timestamp" = "SHIFT_to"), roll=TRUE]

# output
dcast(df, from+to+secs ~ emp , fun = length)[,-"NA"]

#>                   from                  to   secs a b c d e
#> 1: 2019-12-31 22:00:00 2020-01-01 06:00:00      0 0 0 0 0 0
#> 2: 2020-01-01 06:00:00 2020-01-01 14:00:00  28800 1 0 0 0 0
#> 3: 2020-01-01 14:00:00 2020-01-01 22:00:00  57600 0 1 0 0 0
#> 4: 2020-01-01 22:00:00 2020-01-02 06:00:00  86400 0 1 0 0 0
#> 5: 2020-01-02 06:00:00 2020-01-02 14:00:00 115200 0 0 1 0 0
#> 6: 2020-01-02 14:00:00 2020-01-02 22:00:00 144000 0 0 0 1 0
#> 7: 2020-01-02 22:00:00 2020-01-03 06:00:00 172800 0 0 0 0 1
#> 8: 2020-01-03 06:00:00 2020-01-03 14:00:00 201600 0 0 0 0 1
#> 9: 2020-01-03 14:00:00 2020-01-03 22:00:00 230400 0 0 0 0 1
```